# Read all td values with Javascript

Tags: javascript, tabs, html-table

I am trying to get all `td` and compare each `td` value to a string .
but my code only reads the first `td` of each `tr`.

Here is my HTML :

```
<table border="2px" id="tab">
<tr>
<td>color</td>
<td> a </td>
<td> font</td>
<td>123</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>font</td>
<td> color </td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td> color</td>
<td> font</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>font</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

My js code:

```
var t=["color","font","a"];

function color()
{
    var colr=0;
    var tab=[];
    var table = document.getElementById("tab");
    var len=table.rows.length;

for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) 
{

                        for (var j=0; j<table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)

                             {

                                 tab[j]= table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;

                                // alert(tab[j]);
                                if(tab[j]== t[0])
                                 { colr++;}
                             }
  } 

alert(colr);
  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: can you use jquery?

Comment: @AlejandroPérezFals , no am working with js

Answer (score 0):

The spacing in the `<td>` is messing with the comparisons. As your code lies, you're comparing `" color"` to `"color"` and that's returning false, thus seeing as you're only getting that `colr` index going up to 1.

You'll need to strip out the spaces in order to compare properly, example JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/76q3aro3/